# Intel AMT serial over lan in UEFI

Tags: serial-port, intel, osdev, uefi

I am working on a light weight operating system. To debug the OS, I use the serial port to print messages. I run the OS on a laptop and use Intel AMT's serial over lan to transfer the serial output to another computer. The OS's boot and serial output code are similar to [tboot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tboot/). The OS boots using multiboot, which accepts a command line that specifies a serial I/O address.

For example,  I use `serial=115200,8n1,0x3060` when booting my OS. (It is not `serial=115200,8n1,0x3f8` because I am using Intel AMT, not a physical serial port). `0x3060` comes from Linux's dmesg:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep ttyS0
[    2.319851] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3060 (irq = 19, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
$
```

This works well when the OS is booted from BIOS (i.e. from a MBR partition, etc.) However, recently I decided to support UEFI (i.e. boot from GPT partition, etc.), and I can no longer see serial output. Is there some extra thing I need to do to output to Intel AMT's serial over lan in UEFI?

###### Testing on tboot

I also tested tboot. I am using Debian, and I installed tboot via `apt-get install tboot`. Then in GRUB, I changed `multiboot2 /boot/tboot.gz logging=serial,memory` to `multiboot2 /boot/tboot.gz logging=serial,memory serial=115200,8n1,0x3060`. However, nothing shows in the serial output.

###### Testing on Linux

I also tested Linux. I use `linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-14-amd64 root=UUID=... ro  console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600` and it works:

```
...
[    0.029844] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    0.109082] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
...
[    1.249217] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    1.250118] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3060 (irq = 19, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.628170] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
...
```

Looks like the kernel first prints some messages using ttyS0. Then it re-detects the serial port at time 1.250118 and continues printing.

However, when I use `linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-14-amd64 root=UUID=... ro  console=tty0 console=uart8250,io,0x3060,115200n8`, it no longer works:

```
(nothing printed above)
[    2.311240] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3060 (irq = 19, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    2.313644] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    2.313644] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    2.328964] printk: bootconsole [uart8250] disabled
[    2.328964] printk: bootconsole [uart8250] disabled
...
```

This time, looks like Linux is not able to print to the serial port. But after re-detecting the serial port (at 2.311240 this run, which is 1.250118 the last run), Linux is able to print to serial port.

Is Linux performing some extra detections / initializations in order to access the serial port? How can I access the serial port in my OS? You can think this question as "how can I modify tboot to access the serial port in UEFI mode?" I am willing to add a small amount of code.